# Javascript file not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, google-chrome-devtools

I am having a real problem with my javascript file not loading.  I am working on a local environment using Vagrant.  Git is recognizing every change I make to my javascript file but when I refresh the page the changes do not show up in the inspector.  I am definitely editing the right file and I have dumped the cache a thousand times.  Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I've been working on this site everyday for a month and today is the first day this has started.  Any help will be much appreciated.

I am adding the javascript file using:

```
    function wpb_adding_scripts() {
       wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
       wp_enqueue_script('main');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

Comment: what webserver and webframework are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Comment: I am using Wordpress and Bower

Comment: Earlier  today, your changes to this file were getting reflected?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Also, any other files I change (templates, CSS, etc.) show immediate reflection.  Just not my javascript file

Comment: Can you show the template file where you imported javascript file?

Comment: I am adding the scripts in the functions.php file using:

Comment: Hi there, have you tried to disable cache in the dev-tools or to open incognito mode so your files will not be cached?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue.  For anyone who was having a day like I was yesterday...remember to do a wordpress database search and replace (I use this one https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)  on your local whenever you have to replace your local database with a testing/live database.  *Fist in forehead*